# how to implement counters in hadoop streaming in python

Tags: python, hadoop

I am new to hadoop streaming. I have few filter conditions in my reduce code, I would like to know how many records pass this conditions. I come to know we can do this by writing custom counters. Can some body show point me how to write custom counters?

I am emitting three columns in mapper code, say `a,b,c`
key is a, and value as list, which is like `[b,c]`, To have an example from mapper code, it is like `['I'^['C','P']]`

Here is my reduce code.

```
labels = ["a","b"]
for line in sys.stdin:
    l = line.strip().split("^")
    key = l[0]
    value = l[1]
    record = [key] + value
    records.append(record)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records,columns=labels)
df = df((df['a'] == 'I') & (df['b'] == 'C'))
```

I would like to know how many records df contains, at reducer level.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply print to stderr:

```
print >> sys.stderr, "reporter:counter: CUSTOM, NbRecords,1"
```

This will increment counter "NbRecords" in counters group "CUSTOM" by 1

Answer (score 5):

If [using mrjob](http://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/writing-mrjobs.html),

```
class MRCountingJob(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, value):
        self.increment_counter('group', 'counter_name', 1)
        yield _, value
```

If  using the basic [hadoop streaming API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#How_do_I_update_counters_in_streaming_applications) (with python),

```
sys.stderr.write("reporter:counter:group,counter_name,1\n")
```

where, for example, `group` could be `"My Mapper`", `"My Reducer"`, or `"My FooBar"` a counter might be `num_calls`,  and the value will typically always be 1, since these will be summed by the framework. (When using `stderr.write`, don't forget the trailing newline, `\n`)

Comment: How can one access the counter though? Say if Script A ran Hadoop Map Reduce Command, which in turn ran Mapper.py and Reducer.py ? Is there an easy way for Script A to access the counter/see the output?